# How to find the parametric equation

Tags: parametric

I've got this curve and I know its part of a circle,
[image]

From this I should find that $x = a-acos(\theta) $and $y = a-asin(\theta)$ but I don't know how?

Can someone help?

Comment: What other circle equation do you know ? And are you familiar with the trigonometric circle ?

Comment: Can you give more detail, either on what you are looking for or on the problem? From the information given it looks like you have the answer already ($x=a-a\cos(\theta),\ y=a-a\sin(\theta)$).

Comment: I am familiar with the trigonometric circle and polar coordinates. I know $ x^2+y^2 = r^2$ where r is the radius and for a circle at coordinate (h,k) its $ (x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2$. But I don't know how they find $ ( x=a−acos(\theta), y=a−asin(\theta)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quarter-circle in the third quadrant centered at the origin is
$x=-a\cos t, y=-a\sin t$.

Your curve is that with $a$ added to
$x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

From the figure, the radius is $a$ and the center is at $(a,a)$.

To the center coordinates, add the components of the radius at angle $\theta+\pi$,

$$(x,y)=(a+a\cos(\theta+\pi),a+a\sin(\theta+\pi))=(a-a\cos(\theta),a-a\sin(\theta)).$$

Answer (score 0):

The circle has the equation :

$$(x-a)^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$$

so the parametric equations of the portion are

$$x=a+a\cos (t) $$
$$y=a+a\sin (t) $$
with $$\pi \le t \le \frac {3\pi}{2} $$

> or
>   $$x=a-a\cos (u) $$
>   $$y=a-a\sin (u) $$
>   with $$0\le u\le \frac {\pi}{2} $$

Comment: x = a+acos(t) or x = a-acos(t)? and y = a+asin(t) or y = a-asin(t)

Comment: @AyoubRossi my t is in $[\pi, 3\pi/2] $ and yours?

Comment: I would use [0,pi/2]

Comment: @AyoubRossi If you want. i just edited.

Comment: Why does the sign change? I would use a plus even with my t :/

Comment: @AyoubRossi u=t-\pi.

Comment: @AyoubRossi still waiting for your answer.